# ASP NET MVC Error construction INSERT with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with getting identity primary key from a logged user with using sql queries without Enity Framework.
So when i put login and password of user from my database UserDataController copy UserEmail (login) to WorkSpaceController and put it in public ActionResult UploadFile(string useremail) in useremail data. So I can use it in query in WorkSpaceController to get an ID with this email. But the problem is I can't use UserID that i got as a parameter for insert query. Look at the code below

**UserDataController:**

```
public class UserDataController : Controller
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer"].ConnectionString;
    // GET: UserData
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserDataClass log) //Авторизация
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-LRLFA5K\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FileCloud;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from UserData where UserEmail ='" + log.UserEmail + "' and UserPassword ='" + log.UserPassword + "'", con);
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Session["useremail"] = log.UserEmail.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("UploadFile", "WorkSpace", new { useremail = log.UserEmail.ToString()});
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль";
        }
        con.Close();
        return View();
    }
}
```

**WorkSpaceController:**

```
public class WorkSpaceController : Controller
{
    int currentid;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer"].ConnectionString;
    WorkSpaceClass ws = new WorkSpaceClass();
    List<WorkSpaceClass> _ws = new List<WorkSpaceClass>();
    // GET: WorkSpace
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult UploadFile(string useremail)
    {
        UserDataClass info = new UserDataClass();
        info.UserEmail = useremail;
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string comman = "select UserID from UserData where UserEmail = '" + info.UserEmail + "'"; //??? Вероятно, Email пуст...
        using (SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(comman, sqlcon))
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            currentid = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcom.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        //ws.UserID = id; //UserID не читается
        ViewBag.UserID = currentid;
        sqlcon.Close();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase doc, string useremail) //Загружаем текстовый файл в БД
    {
        ViewBag.UserEmail = useremail;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            ws.FileName = Path.GetFileName(doc.FileName);
            ws.FileData = new byte[doc.ContentLength];
            doc.InputStream.Read(ws.FileData, 0, doc.ContentLength);
            ws.FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(ws.FileName);
            DateTime FileDate = DateTime.Now;

            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(constr);

            ws.FileDate = FileDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            if (ws.FileExtension == ".doc" || ws.FileExtension == ".docx" || ws.FileExtension == ".txt" || ws.FileExtension == ".pdf")
            {
                string FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FileData"), ws.FileName); //Указываем дирректорию хранения файла
                doc.SaveAs(FilePath); 
                string command = "insert into FileData(FileName, FileData, FileExtension, FileDate, UserID) values(@FileName, @FileData, @FileExtension, @FileDate, @UserID)";
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(command, sqlcon);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ws.FileName;
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = ws.FileData;
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@FileExtension", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ws.FileExtension;
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@FileDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ws.FileDate;
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currentid; //AN ERROR IS HERE
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery(); //BUT THIS ROW IS DISPLAY ON ERROR LOG AND COLORED AS RED
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
        }
        return View(ws);
    }
```

**WorkSpaceClass:**

```
public class WorkSpaceClass
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string FileDate { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

**WorkSpaceClass:**

```
public class UserDataClass
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите имя пользователя")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Email")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Пароль")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите пароль")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Подтверждение пароля")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Подтвердите пароль")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Выберите изображение")]
    public byte[] AvatarData { get; set; }
}
```

[This is columns types from SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2KHl.jpg)

So if I put any int number like 1 or 2 in a row (sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currentid;) on "currentid" place file will be uploaded to a current user with this id.
I think the problem is the row "currentid = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcom.ExecuteScalar());" but I can't imagine how to resolve it.
Hope u help guys, I stuck with it for a 2 days already. I'm a new in MVC ASP.NET so this error can be a typically for you...
With ViewBag i tested values that i got and it was the right id int value from current email that on "useremail".

Comment: Don't build your own authentication system. Your query is vulnerable for SQL injectionl; a username of `admin@site.ru' --` will log you in as admin, whether the password is correct or not. As for your actual problem, what exactly is the issue? Does your code throw an exception? Where? And for which values?

Comment: @CodeCaster the full error name is:
"Server Error in '/' Application. The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY "FK__FileData__UserID__3E1D39E1". The conflict occurred in database "FileCloud", table "dbo.UserData", column 'UserID'. The statement has been terminated."
Error Source: row 71: sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery(); in WorkSpaceController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but the error explains itself. This code is inserting `FileData` for a `UserID` that doesn't exists in table `UserData`; and the reason for that it's the value for `currentid` getting lost.

When you reach `UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase doc, string useremail)` you're in a new request so `ViewData` and `ViewBag` won't help and `currentid` got lost. You need either `TempData`, `Session` or a new parameter in this controller action method to retrieve value for `UserId`. If you have previously saved the value in `TempData`, try this:

```c#
if(TempData["UserId"] != null)
{
  ---
  ---
  sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)TempData["UserId"];
  ---
}
```